# Is there any plugins to automatically optimize Eclipse.ini file?

Tags: eclipse, optimization, ini

it seems to be so tricky to have a really optimized "eclipse.ini" file.
I need to load multiple OSGi projects in the work space and develop and compile them parallel.

I have some tries to optimize the .ini file, but never could be sure this is the best choice.

Do you know any automatic optimizer plugin or gadget which handles the job using system preferences?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What kind of optimization?  Memory?  If that's the case then I'd look for articles on how to optimize Java programs in general.

Comment: @RoyTruelove hi roy, yes I exactly have the idea of having a dynamic eclipse plugin to optimize parameters we've currently set in the .ini file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Optimizer For Eclipse](http://zeroturnaround.com/blog/announcing-optimizer-for-eclipse-a-jetpack-for-eclipse/), from [ZeroTurnaround](http://zeroturnaround.com/) helps with this.

**What does it help with?**

- Insufficient memory allocation
- Class verification overhead
- Excessive indexes and history
- Obsolete or slow JDK
- Eclipse being out of date
- Lengthy build and redeploy times

For more details, check out this [article from RebelLabs](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/eclipse-having-a-slow-day-speed-it-up-in-a-few-clicks/).

Answer (score 3):

[Optimizer For Eclipse](http://zeroturnaround.com/blog/announcing-optimizer-for-eclipse-a-jetpack-for-eclipse/), from the jrebel team, does exactly this.